# Output of tree in command prompt

Tags: tree, cmd

I was hoping to be able to use the

```
tree /F /A > "desktop"\file.txt
```

command to output only text files. Currently as is, it outputs every file extension.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Tree` accepts only a few command line parameters:

```
c:\>Tree /?
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

None of the indicated parameters are a file mask or filter.

You can use `dir` with the proper switches, and redirect the output to a text file. You'll get the full path name to the files, but you can filter that out in later processing if need be with a `for` loop:

```
C:\>dir *.txt /s /b > filelist.txt
```

Comment: Note - the command prompt was locked down on the server I was trying the tree function on.  It worked best to use the 'dir' command inside a .cmd file.

Answer (score 13):

It's actually not that hard to get your desired TREE output using FINDSTR regular expressions. :-)

```
tree /f /a | findstr /ri /c:"^[^| ]" /c:"^[| ]*[+\\]" /c:"\.txt$"
```

Comment: Not that hard? This is some wizard level stuff +1

Comment: I wish to understand how you get to this solution, also this should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

Note: that `tree` command does not order the output by name!

Instead you can use this approach:

```
dir /b /s /ad /on c:\ > c:\file.txt
```

Result looks like less nice but

[reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true)

[this solution found on Superuser by pbies](https://superuser.com/a/718681/65130)

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option:  Go to the directory you want to list out, type in CMD so you are already in the right place, then:

> tree /a /f>"output.doc"

That will put it into a word doc, easier to edit and format from there.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler.

You just need to export your result like this:
`tree /a /f >"toto.rtf"`

Then you open the file with *Word* and choose `MS DOS` convert.

Comment: How does that suppress files that are not `.txt`?