# Generate a list or map of css files

Tags: css

I'm starting to work on a new app at my company. I'm hoping to run a quick process that will generate an outline, tree, or other map-type thing of all of the CSS and SASS files in the app directory.

I know I can grep it, but I wanted to see if someone had something more targeted I could use.

Comment: So you want a file browser?

Comment: I think I want something more focused, maybe it shows which sass files get compiled into which css files, where all of the sass and css files are located, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply looking to generate a tree, the common `tree` command can filter by file type if provided a pattern. Maybe this will help:

```
tree -P "*.css" --prune
```

The -P option allows you to match a pattern, and the --prune option hides empty folders (or ones which don't contain match files).

It's a pretty nifty tool; here's some sample output from `tree -P "*.js" --prune` on a node project directory:

```
.
├── Authorize.js
├── collections.js
├── functions
│   ├── downloadImage.js
│   ├── generateThumbnails.js
│   ├── hashImage.js
│   ├── loadMedia.js
│   └── uploadFile.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── body-parser
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── read.js
│   │   │   └── types
│   │   │       ├── json.js
│   │   │       ├── raw.js
│   │   │       ├── text.js
│   │   │       └── urlencoded.js
│   │   └── node_modules
│   │       ├── bytes
│   │       │   └── index.js
│   │       ├── content-type
│   │       │   └── index.js
```

More documentation here: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm

Comment: Whoa. That's a nifty tool. The `tree` command on Windows is (unsurprisingly) not that advanced - would there be a comparable set of commands for Windows, or would it be simpler to just use a Linux shell (ie, `git bash`) instead?

Comment: I'm not really sure, to be honest, I don't often use the Windows command line. I found this, however, which seems to suggest that there is indeed a way to filter files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11006036/1112127. The patterns seem to be much more complex, however.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't see that. It's definitely more complex. Thanks for finding that!

Comment: Close enough for me! Thank you.